# use JNDI connection factory in MDB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ibm-mq

We migrated MDB from IBM web sphere to Jboss 7. Our messaging broker is IBM MQ and we are using resource adapter to communicate. We defined jms connection factory at JNDI level in Jboss 7, we would like to use in our EJB.

we tried to put in ejb-jar.xml, But its not worked, any other solutions?

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>MessageBean</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.hi.helloMessageBean</ejb-class>
                <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>






                 <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>jms/queue_1</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>connectionFactoryJndiName</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>jms/connec_fact_1</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>



                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>  
                        useJNDI  
                    </activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>  
                        true  
                    </activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>



</activation-config>                


        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <d:delivery>
            <ejb-name>essageBean</ejb-name>
            <d:active>true</d:active> <!-- Change to false, to disable MDB delivery. -->
        </d:delivery>
        <container-transaction>
             <method>
                  <ejb-name>MessageBean</ejb-name>
                  <method-name>*</method-name>
             </method>
            <trans-attribute>RequiresNew</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>        
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know how to answer your question wit the limited information provided.  If you are getting a "name not found" exception, all JNDI names should be of the form:

```
java:jboss/jms/queue_1
```

The JNDI names in all of the configuration files should exactly match what you see in the JNDI view in the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you would most likely be better off setting `useJNDI` to `false`, and setting the `destination` name to be the IBM MQ queue name.  There are only a few cases where you need to define the queue in the resource adapter section of the JBoss server configuration file.